# turtle-own variable defined by a global distribution around a determined mean and a given scale

Tags: statistics, netlogo, seed

I try to assign a turtle own variable "X" according to it's global distribution. Each turtle-own x should be a random seed between 0 and 20. BUT it must be dependent on the global distribution: The overall random distribution of X of all turtles, must depend on a determined and changeable mean.

I thought about achieving this with *random-gamma* but I have no idea how to stick to the scale.

Further, during the runs, the number of turtles increases due to offspring. each new turtle needs to get a value for the variable X. The mean and the scale should always stay the same which was determined in the setup. All living turtles should keep their X.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: well I dont have a code, that's the problem

Comment: Then write some code with your random-gamma idea and come back with the specific problem about scales by showing us what it does compared to what you want it to do. SO helps you to fix your code so it does what you want, not to write code for you from scratch.